# Is it possible to get the deleted file from Eclipse workspace?

Tags: java, eclipse, recover

I have accidentally deleted a Java file from my Eclipse workspace.

Can i recover that? It's not in the recycle bin.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Check this page: [How to restore deleted files in Eclipse](http://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-87b.htm)

> Suppose you have deleted any file by mistake. No need to worry. Deleted files can be restored from the history.
>
> **How to Do**:
>
> Right click on the project and open the context menu. And go for the menu item "Restore from Local History...".

Answer (score 9):

I think [local history](http://www.aaronwest.net/blog/index.cfm/2007/3/23/Do-You-Know-About-Eclipses-Local-History) can help you.

Answer (score 3):

- Just recreate the *same* file in *same* location.
- Right click >
  `Replace With` > `Local History...`.
- Select the appropriate file data
  from history.

Comment: `Restore from Local History...` works without having the recreate the file.

Comment: @greg449 - Thanks for letting me know; I was not finding this `Restore from Local History...` in my earlier version of Eclipse, but the above option always worked, so thought of putting it here.

Answer (score 0):

yes...
Right Click on Project in which u want to restore those files...
Right Click > Restore From Local History > (Select files) > Restore

Answer (score 0):

only "Compare With" --> "Local History" did it for me. shows dates as well. (thank god!)