# Project lost in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, project

I almost finish my app for android and my coursework is due in 10 days.
I've deleted my project from Eclipse. I've got the runnable version installed on AVD.
Is there any way to transfer back to Eclipse?

> MAC OS X 10.8.2
>   Eclipse for Mobile Developers
>   Version: Juno Service Release 1
>   Build id: 20120920-0800

Comment: As you have learned... Backup on a regular basis.

Comment: taking backup on regular basis is required as u never know when you will need or lose any important data

Comment: Data on your disk is not deleted entirely. You should investigate data recovery tools.

Answer (score 1):

Check out these two links http://www.java-tips.org/other-api-tips/eclipse/how-to-restore-deleted-files-in-eclipse.html

http://www.nodans.com/index.cfm/2008/1/18/How-to-recover-a-deleted-file-in-Eclipse

and an answer to this question here [Is it possible to get the deleted file from Eclipse workspace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5451175/is-it-possible-to-get-the-deleted-file-from-eclispe-workspace)

You can get back your project by using **Restore from Local History** option explained how to do on the links i have provided

Comment: i've tried but it didn't work.it says: "No additional members found on local history".I guess i'll have to start from scratch.

Comment: you are having a metadata folder somewhere in where you installed eclipse did you checked .metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.history/ here and please follow this lik http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_Where_is_the_workspace_local_history_stored%3F hope it helps you rather than starting from scratch

Answer (score 0):

Did you also delete it from your disk? Have a look into eclipse's `workspace` directory. To get a clue where that is, do `File > Workspace > Other ...` and have a look at the proposed places. Click `Cancel` here.

If your project is still there, use `File > Import > Android > Existing Android Code` in Eclipse to get your project back.

Comment: yes, unfortunately i've deleted from my disk

Answer (score 0):

If you have .class file of it you can try out to reconvert it in to java project.
Find on Google the class file convertor.